# error code: 1054. Unknown column "x" in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

so I'm posting on behalf of someone since I have a stack account and they do not. Saying that, I do not know much about SQL, simply posting this question from her mouth to this.

Selecting the code from #1 --

```
create table employee


(
FNAME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
MINIT char(1),
LNAME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
SSN int NOT NULL,
BDATE date NOT NULL,
ADDRESS varchar(150),
SEX char(1) NOT NULL,
SALARY decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
SUPERSSN int NULL,
DNO int null,

PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
INDEX (SSN)
)
;

use employee;

--#1
select BDate, Address from employee
where FNAME='John' and MINIT='B' and LNAME='Smith';
```

throws the error code 1054 saying "Unknock column, 'BDate' in 'field list'"

Can anyone point her in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated. If needed, I can post the entire database code.

Comment: I think it's pretty self-explanatory.  Unknown column, meaning BDate isn't a column in the employee table.

Comment: does the employee table have the column BDATE ? should be the exact name spelling as BDATE.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan, Yes, I will edit that part of the code into my question.

Comment: Why are you specifying `use employee;` in between the `create` and `select`?  You use `use` to switch databases not tables.

Comment: Did the create command create the table successfully ?

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan, Yes it did.

Answer (score 1):

Use employee refers to another database with (probably) another employee table in it (which has different fields) .  Please remove the use and try again.
Check which database you created the above employee table.
Use is used to refer to databases  not tables.

Comment: Removed the "use" and still getting the same error -- Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: I made the exact same table , input the same values and ran the same query and it gave me the output  ?? what else could be wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Your table is created with the column `ADDRESS`, while your query is trying to locate the column `Address`.

<s>Of course they are not the same thing, so you have an error.</s>

<s>Same for the column `BDATE`.</s>

**Correction**

MySql is case insensitive (checked just now on my 5.5.40), but it returns the row with the same case used for the query, so I think it's preferable to keep some consistency between PHP and MySql: PHP variables are case sensitive.

Comment: I believe MySQL is not case sensitive on column names.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan - You're right, my mistake. I didn't check.